# What are the consequences of setting the NLS_TERRITORY to America on a DB in UK?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We have databases set up for NLS_TERRITORY = America and NLS_CURRENCY = $ and NLS_CHARSET = AL32UTF8

This database is a UK client database and has nothing to do with US. So I was wondering whether to leave it or whether to fix it.

What are the consequences of leaving it or whether it is a problem at all?

Answer (score 2):

I know that in America Sunday is first day of week, in UK - Monday. Currency of course is GBP (£) not USD.

And default date format in UK is dd/mm/yyyy, in USA - mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

The character set should support any unicode (non-ascii characters) which you may need to store/display but NLS_CURRENCY may cause any data formatted to money to use the $ symbol instead of £. In theory this is unlikely to be a problem.

Territory may cause more of a problem as it could affect the way dates and numbers are formatted. You'll have to see if this is going to cause a problem for the data you are storing and the way you present it.

It's probably fairly easy for you to change these settings by altering database parameters or altering session. e.g.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_* = <value> SCOPE = SPFILE;

or ALTER SESSION
```